# About the issue of undefined after update ajax in laravel

Tags: php

I am implementing the comment editing function.. edit function is successfully on database but In web after ajax text is return 'undefined '. but if i use 'location.reload();' function Web is show the text successfully in database returns.

but i don't want to use 'location.reload();'
I want to know why the word "undefined" comes out.
I'm using a translator

this is my code

```html
<div class="content mt-4 rounded-3 border border-secondary">
        @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @if ($comment->product_id == $productId && $comment->flow_num == $flow)
        <p>
            comment : <span id="comment{{ $comment->id }}">{{ $comment->comments }}</span>
            <button type="" class="btn btn-success confirm-btn">ok</button>
            <button type="" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit{{ $comment->id }}" onclick="editComment({{ $comment->id }})" type="submit">edit</button>
            {{-- <form action="{{ route('comment.delete') }}" method="post" id="deleteForm{{ $comment->id }}"> --}}
            <form action="" method="POST" id="deleteForm{{ $comment->id }}">
                @csrf
                {{-- @method('delete') --}}
                <input type="hidden" name="comment-id" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmDelete({{ $comment->id }})">delete</button>
            </form>
        </p>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

```js
 function editComment(commentId) {
        const commentSpan = document.getElementById(`comment${commentId}`);
        const editButton = document.getElementById(`edit${commentId}`);

        if (commentSpan && editButton) {
            const commentText = commentSpan.innerText;
            const inputElement = document.createElement('input');
            inputElement.type = 'text';
            inputElement.value = commentText;
            inputElement.name = `comment${commentId}`;
            inputElement.classList.add('form-control');

            commentSpan.innerText = '';
            commentSpan.appendChild(inputElement);

            editButton.innerText = 'save';
            editButton.onclick = () => saveComment(commentId); // saveComment
        }
    }


    function saveComment(commentId) {
        const commentSpan = document.getElementById(`comment${commentId}`);
        const editButton = document.getElementById(`edit${commentId}`);
        const inputElement = commentSpan.querySelector('input');

        if (inputElement) {
            const commentText = inputElement.value;
            //AJAX
            fetch("{{ route('comment.update') }}", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    commentId: commentId,
                    commentText: commentText
                })
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to save comment');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                commentSpan.innerText = data.commentText;
                editButton.innerText = 'edit';
                editButton.onclick = () => editComment(commentId);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                alert('failed');
                // location.reload();
            });
        }
    }
```

Controller code

```php
public function update(Request $request, comments $comments)
    {

        $requestDataId = $request->commentId;
        $requestDataText = $request->commentText;


        try {
            
            $comment = comments::where('id', $requestDataId)->first();
            if (!$comment) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'cant find'], 404);
            }


            $comment->comments = $requestDataText;
            $comment->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            Log::error($e->getMessage());

            return response()->json(['error' => 'error'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJaHr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVitJ.png)

Comment: Your JSON response only ever contains `success` (totally useless) or `error` properties. If you want `commentText`, you'll need to set it... `return response()->json(['commentText' => $comment->comments]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the word undefined because you didn't include the 'ok' property in the response received from the controller if (!response.ok)

Add the ok property to all responses according to the truth value and add after $comment->save() a new return. You used 'error' or 'success' for nothing if you don't use them in your javascript code.

Example

```
$comment->save();
return response()->json(['ok' => true]);
```

or

```
return response()->json([['ok' => false, 'error' => 'cant find'], 404);
```

I suggest you use property "ok" as boolean and "message" as text to capture success or error message.